# "TO" FOR PURPOSE

Tags: to-infinitive

Does "to" in the following sentences express purpose?

- She was busy all day. She didn't have a moment **to** rest.
- He loved her but he didn't have the courage **to** tell her.
- My friend helped me to find a house **to** rent.

Comment: No, not at all..

Comment: What are the role of the infinitival clause after these "to"? complements?

Comment: Here "Infinitive phrase " act as a modifiers. It's giving more information about it's immediate previous noun.

Comment: Infinitives of purpose can be expressed either as "in order to X" or just "to X". None of these can be expressed as "in order to X" and keep the same meaning